# Updating Apollo store when mutating list filter

Tags: javascript, graphql, apollo, react-apollo

I have a graphql schema that looks like this :

```
type User {
    entries(status: EntryStatus): [Entry]
}

type Mutation {    
    updateEntry(status: EntryStatus): Entry
}
```

I can filter the list of entries by status (which is an enum) and I can update the status of an entry. I'd like to update the store when the status is updated so that the entry appears in the right list (`entries(status: FOO)` to `entries(status: BAR)`).

I know I can update the store with the [`update`](http://dev.apollodata.com/react/api-mutations.html#graphql-mutation-options-update) method.

```
const withMutation = graphql(updateEntryMutation, {
  props: ({ mutate }) => ({
    updateEntry: updateEntryInput =>
      mutate({
        variables: { updateEntryInput },
        update: (proxy, newData) => {

          // update data here
          // Which would involve removing the entry from its previous filtered "list", and adding it to the one with the new status

      })
  })
});
```

**But how can I know from which list to remove the entry since I don't have access to the old data (previous entry.status) from `update` ?**

*(apart from enumerating all lists by status and removing the updated entry if I find it...)*

Answer (score 0):

You need to `store.readQuery()` first, then write the new data to the store.

Kinda like this:

```
const EntriesQuery = 'yourQueryHere';

const withMutation = graphql(updateEntryMutation, {
  props: ({ mutate }) => ({
    updateEntry: updateEntryInput =>
      mutate({
        variables: { updateEntryInput },
        update: (store, { data: { updateEntry }}) => {

          const data = store.readQuery({ query: EntriesQuery });
          data.entries.push(updateEntry)

          store.writeQuery({ query: EntriesQuery, data })
      })
  })
});
```